# is there a command in C language that checks if the user has entered input or not without waiting for input

Tags: c

e.g the user may enter `l`s or `ls command`. This command may not appear every time. How can I check if the user has entered the command or not? incase of `scanf()`, if the command exists, the program works fine, but if the command does not exist then it will wait for an input. I don't want the program to wait for this input

Comment: Well there's `kbhit()`/`_kbhit()`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58w7c94c(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: There's no such thing as 'command' in C. There are statements, expressions and functions.

Comment: @PaulR isn't that Windows-specific?

Comment: Apparently `_kbhit()` is ISO: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235390(v=vs.80).aspx.

Comment: @PaulR, I don't know what ISO is for you, but I can't find that function in my version of the C standard.

Comment: You can use `getchar()` for this purpose.

Comment: @Jens: well I'm just quoting from MSDN, where is says (see link above) that _kbhit is "ISO C++ conformant", but MSDN is not exactly "gospel" of course.

Comment: @PaulR, it certainly isn't gospel, don't mean what they could mean with "conformant", perhaps that it doesn't violate the standard? And, then C++ wouldn't count here anyway, this is C.

Comment: MS probably just make stuff up as they go along. ;-) I guess kbhit has been around for a long time as a non-standard thing (I think it goes all the way back to Turbo C and conio.h). I don't know of any alternative though - I don't think even ncurses has this kind of functionality ? (Also it turns out that I apparently misunderstood the question and the OP isn't even looking for this kind of behaviour anyway.)

Answer (score 3):

[select](http://linux.die.net/man/2/select) can be used for this purpose. Thereby you can query stdin (with timeout, or non-blocking), if there's something to read, before you'd do your (blocking) read.

> select() and pselect() allow a program to monitor multiple file descriptors, waiting until one or more of the file descriptors become "ready" for some class of I/O operation (e.g., input possible). A file descriptor is considered ready if it is possible to perform the corresponding I/O operation (e.g., read(2)) without blocking.

Comment: @H2CO3 what makes you assume this?

Comment: @moooooooooooo the fact that there's always *something* to read; the question is whether there are multiple tokens or just one.

Comment: PS. this program is supposed to run on ubuntu terminal.

Comment: @user1686651 I think you need to further describe what you want to achieve in your question.

Comment: @user1686651 then you should accept an answer. Probably either that one suggesting the use of `fgets()` or provide a self-answer how you solved the problem instead.

Answer (score 0):

All the standard C library input functions are line-oriented which means they wait until the user enters something, or at least hits the enter key.

If you want to respond to input more interactively than that then you will need to use something outside the standard library.  Exactly what you have available will depend on what platform you're coding for.

Comment: what I mean is if the user enters eg "ls private", I will use scanf() which will store ls in a variable. now I use a string compare function. If the string matches, then the program should check if there's anything else already written after ls. if yes then that should be scanned and further compared. but if the user only enters "ls" then it should simply go to else part of the program.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `scanf`. Instead, use `fgets` to read an entire line. *Then* process the line, e.g. tokenize it (`strtok`) and figure out how many words it contains:

```
char buf[1024];

fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin);    // returns after user presses Enter
                                  // (should check that this is not NULL)
char * p = strtok(buf, " \t\n");
while (p)
{
    // p now points to a token
    p = strtok(NULL, " \t\n");
}
```